# GEMM with single-precision and double-precision matrix in BLAS

Tags: c, blas

I am writing some linear algebra program with openBLAS.
The program needs to multiply two matrices; the one is of single-precision and the other one is of double-precision.

I looked up the BLAS reference "http://netlib.org/blas/blasqr.pdf", it seems that BLAS only supports operations on the same type.

Is there anything I miss? Or, to multiply two matrices with different precision, do I need to typecast the single-precision matrix and then multiply them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to upcast the single-precision matrix (or downcast the double-precision one) *and* use `dgemm` (or `sgemm`, resp.)